# Unable to connect to MySQL with ODBC Driver

Tags: mysql, microsoft-access, odbc

I'm unable to connect to MySQL via *Remote MySQL* using *ODBC Driver* for our Microsoft Access Application. I have the same setup at the office and it's working fine but not at home.

That's my setup.
1. Downloaded latest **MySQL ODBC Connector** from MySQL site.
2. Using 32bit driver to match Access *x86*.
3. On the MySQL side, **User** is created and connected to Database with all Privileges.
4. Whitelisted our Public IP.

Here is one thing that I should mention which might be affecting. Our **ISP** for our Office and my home is same, and I found that the Public IP of our Office internet and home is nearly same, and the White Listed IP on Remote MySQL page is like `123.456.789.%` *(**%** Wildcard used for range)*.

I still don't get what is preventing me from connecting to the MySQL database. I need help

Comment: If you are using identical connection string and user at both locations then that would suggest a firewall/router issue perhaps at your home.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I'm already aware that _Remote Connection_ to MySQL is less secure, and no one has a better solution to secure properly because thier are tons of things to consider, but currently an Strong Password has been assigned to user and IPs are being used to allow the connection...

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Sometimes you must connect to MySQL remotely. It is not his company network anyway, it is a remote MySQL database. He also already mentioned locking it down to only accept from a particular IP range as well.

Comment: @topshot OK I got that wrong, but still company data is affected -> pro knowledge needed.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, you are creating distraction here. I Myself am Graduated from the IT Department, it's not like I'm new. I'm already working on two online software **Front Accounting** and **Odoo**, to move MS Access Data to there, but it can take time and I don't want our company stops working till then, so I'm setting up a temporary setup until online setup. This is a worst-case scenario...

Comment: and if you think that this is insecure to work with remote MySQL, then remember that Microsoft Access is even worst. Anyone can crack the Access Front-end and Database with free software available online...

Comment: @MurtazaAbbasi, Sorry for distraction, but you caused this by hiding information. From your question I assumed you using ms access as frontend and MySQL as backend. No word of data migration (any reason you don't create an sql-dump from access and import to MySQL?). You don't provide any error or log infos. All that made me consider you don't know what you're doing.  Please add that info to question and I delete my comments. Last words: I wouldn't even suggest ms-access as local backend, but it is a great RAD local frontend .